# Adding sub-websites (using a domain)

Tags: html

Sorry if the title is confusing but I'll try to explain what I mean.
I was wondering how I can add a "sub-website" (in my words) when buying a domain.
For example, the main website is `google.com`, and the sub-website is `maps.google.com`.
Is this possible without buying another domain?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so your question will end up being closed. The answer is yes, though; your domain registrar and/or hosting provider should have a tutorial on configuring subdomains, and you don't have to pay extra for the subdomains.

Comment: See [this diagram](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/60f1a490a90ed8713c41c36c/1628807693445-MJX2ZG1CAYVBGG37CGUU/image-asset.jpeg) that explains the structure of any typical URL. What you're referring to is called a "sub-domain" and is part of the "root domain" ownership, which is often used to divide up applications/websites as your example of Google apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay buddy you need to go to your WEB HOSTING site and login to your cpanel and you'll find a link called sub domains. that's it you can put a sub domain in there!

Comment: and yeah if you already have a domain name you don't need to buy another one.